# Using lock( ) C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, thread-safety

Why is this lock not working?

CheckActivity is generated from Mouse/Keyboard Windows hook. Any hint how to make this lock to work?

```
    private void CheckActivity(KeyboardMouseKey k)
    {
        lock(this)
        {
            if (_map)
            {
                _map = false;
                if (openFileDialogSelectAudio.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    MapSound(k, openFileDialogSelectAudio.FileName);
            }
            else
            {
                ///play
                foreach (var m in _mappings.Where(m => m.Key.Equals(k)))
                    m.Value.Play();
            }
            UpdateGui();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is there a compiler error, runtime exception, unexpected output, or other unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `lock(this)`.

If Check Activity is called on different objects, lock(this) will not prevent for making sure that only one thread is executing CheckActivity (which appears to be the purpose of the lock)

Use `lock` on static object to make it work.

Example:

```
 private static readonly object lockObj = new object();
 ...
 lock(lockObj)
 {
  ....


 }
```

Comment: There's absolutely no indication that this is the problem, and you've given no explanation of the situations in which it *might* be the problem.

Comment: This answer was the correct, sorry for not pointing out the specific error but it was just that the lock was "not locking"